# retrieving multiple select values

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts

I am using a multi select dropdown which is populated dynamically. How do I retrieve all the selected values from the dropdown list? I am using struts and here is the code from the JSP.

```
<html:select= name="HForm" property="selPerson" multiple="multiple"> 
   <logic:iterate id="pplist" name="HForm" property="personList">
     <option value=<bean:write name="pplist" property="id"/>><bean:write name="pplist"     
      property="value"/></option>
    </logic:iterate> 
</html:select>
```

Currently I am trying to retrieve the selected values by using the below method on the form object, but this returns all the values from the dropdown. I only need the ones selected by the user.

```
hform.getPersonList
```

Form oject: `HForm.java`

```
  private List personList=new ArrayList();
  private List selPerson=new ArrayList();
```

I tried using `hmf.getselPerson();` but this throws an error:

`PropertyUtils E org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean invokeMethod Method invocation failed. 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`

Comment: I suppose you need the value from the property `selPerson` instead of `personList`?

Comment: I tried hmf.getSelPerson(); but this throws an error PropertyUtils E org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean invokeMethod Method invocation failed. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch.

Comment: What is the return type of the `getSelPerson()` method ? It should be `String[]` for a multiselect dropdown.

Comment: thanks a ton! I changed it to String[] from array and it worked. I need to mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I'll post an "official" answer then, for the record ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of the `getSelPerson()` method should be `String[]` for a multiselect dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html:select property="selectedOption" styleId="exemple" multiple="multiple">                 
        <html:optionsCollection property="availableOption" label="name" value="ref" />
</html:select>
```

very easy way...

- selectedOption would be a string[] declared in my java form (with getter and setter)
- availableOption would be an ArrayList of object I want to display for selection (here display name) (getter and setter need to be created also)